# How to run code after custom-set-variables?

Tags: spacemacs

I like to set my color theme programmatically, on the basis of my current system color scheme, like so:

```
(if (string-equal (gsettings-get "org.gnome.desktop.interface" "color-scheme")
                  "prefer-light")
      (load-theme 'sanityinc-solarized-light t)
    (load-theme 'sanityinc-solarized-dark t))
```

I want to run this on Emacs startup. But my color scheme also gets saved to my custom settings, so I need to wait until after `custom-set-variables` has done its thing or it might override my theme choice.

I don't know how to do this waiting. `after-init-hook` and `emacs-startup-hook` both seem to be too early, and adding `:after` advice to `custom-set-variables` doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm using Spacemacs, and I'm really unclear on how it handles startup hook stuff in general, so I might be way off base here. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: If you'd like to set the theme via the if, then why do you also want to set it via `custom-set-variables`, only to overwrite it again after?

Comment: It's not that I want to (in fact I would prefer not to), just that if I do a `load-theme` it gets saved to my custom file. If I could avoid that happening in the first place, that would be a nice solution too :)

Comment: Well, actually... now that I mess around with my custom file a bit, that doesn't seem to be true. I guess I'm not sure how I wound up with a color theme setting in there. Maybe I understand this problem even less than I thought.

Comment: Haha... it is fine (maybe you have used `customize-themes`), anyway, just delete those lines from the `custom-set-variables`, and use the `if` thing in your dotfile

Comment: Yep, that's done it! I still don't really know how this is _supposed_ to work, but it's fine for my purposes. Cheers!

Comment: I've posted a reply as an answer (as 'real' answers are preferred for answering), I hope it somewhat takes away the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either configure things 'manually' or otherwise you can use the customize interface. As you have found, when using the customize interface this always gets priority as `custom-set-variables` is always loaded last. So if you have customized things, but would like to 'switch to manual' configuration, then you should remove configurations from the `custom-set-variables`. You can either remove it directly in the dotfile, or use the `revert` button with `erase-customization` in the customize interface.